# how to make args only read certain words

Tags: node.js, discord

im coding a discord bot, i need help with a command im coding: sr!coin
heres the code:

```
        case "coin":
      if (args[1] === "heads", "tails") {
        message.channel.sendMessage(`Your bet: ${args[1]}, outcome: ${coins[Math.floor(Math.random() * coins.length)]}`);
      } else {
        message.channel.sendMessage('Your arguments must include of sr!coin heads or sr!coin tails!');
      }
```

it outputs no error just accepts other args besides heads and tails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement `if (args[1] === "heads", "tails"){...}` doesn't do what you want it to do.

I think you're looking for:

```
if (args[1] === "heads" || args[1] === "tails"){....}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `args` ? Is it `process.argv.slice(2)` ? If yes, do :

```
if (['heads','tails'].includes(args[1]))
```